# Update Query for string replace in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have table,

```
   id        Name   

   1      aaaaAAbbbb 
   2      bbbbAAaaaa 
   3      aabbAAbbaa
```

This is my table,i want to update 'AA' with 'BB' using sql server 2008

Comment: Did you try something ? What is problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update myTable set [Name] = REPLACE([Name], 'AA', 'BB')
```

`REPLACE` applies to [SQL Server 2008 upwards.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...but this will update all 'a' with 'B'..i want Only AA with BB

Comment: This probably means that your collation is set to case-insensitive. You can get around this by specifiying the collation that `REPLACE` should apply (see the link I referenced).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 REPLACE(Name,'AA','BB');
```

and update you column.